# How to position tables in ie 9 using css?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using the following code to position table . It displays well in firefox and chrome but the table gets stick on the left edge of the internet explorer 9 but it should be on the right . Can someone suggest some modifications to this code to display it properly in internet explorer ?

Html code :

```
<table class="tab1">
 <thead>
<tr>    
<th  scope="col" id="Dimension"><strong>DIMENSIONS</strong></th>
<th  scope="col" id="Feet"><strong>FEET</strong></th>
</tr>

</thead>  
</tbody>
<tr class="disp-Sing-Spc
">  
<th class="color1" scope="col">A (Distance Between Signs)</th>
<th class="color1" scope="col" id="A">100</th>
</tr>
<tr class="disp-Sing-Spc
">
<th class="color2" scope="col">B (Distance Between Signs)</th>
<th class="color2" scope="col" id="B">100</th>
</tr>
<tr class="disp-Sing-Spc
">
<th class="color1" scope="col">C (Distance Between Signs)</th>
<th class="color1" scope="col" id="C">100</th>
</tr>
<tr id="disp-Tpr-Len">
<th class="color2" scope="col">L (Taper Length)</th>
<th class="color2" scope="col" id="Tpr-Len">None</th>
</tr>
<tr class="disp-cn-spc
">
<th class="color1" scope="col">Maximum Taper Channelizing Device Spacing</th>
<th class="color1" scope="col" id="max-taper-dv-spcing">None</th>
</tr>
<tr class="disp-cn-spc
">
<th class="color2" scope="col">Suggested Taper Channelizing Device Spacing</th>
<th class="color2" scope="col" id="Sugg-tpr-dev-spcing">None</th>
</tr>
<tr class="disp-cn-spc
">
<th class="color1" scope="col">Maximum Tangent Channelizing Device Spacing</th>
<th class="color1" scope="col" id="Max-Tgt-dev-Spcing">None</th>
</tr>
<tr class="disp-cn-spc
">
<th class="color2" scope="col">Suggested Tangent Channelizing Device Spacing</th>
<th class="color2" scope="col" id="Sugg-Tgt-dev-Spcing">None</th>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

CSS Code :

```
    .tab1{
border-collapse: collapse;
position: absolute;
right: 2%;
top: 95px;
width: 25%;
background: #EA9949;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my IE9 it looks fine, however without the 2% right margin. You should try to float your div and use fixed values.

```
.tab1{
border-collapse: collapse;
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
float:right;
top: 95px;
width: 300px;
background: #EA9949;
}
```

By the way, you should get read of the tables and use divs instead.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8q6bG/ , you should try it before posting your answer.

Comment: In your last edit it works because you changed the width value, it will work the same without the "float", this is not answering the question.

Comment: @Josep Yes it worked, even on the link you posted... perhaps you didn't understand what he asked... anyway you should try to help next time instead of posting useless comments.